# Persisting Journal Requests and stub request to keep instances in sync when wiremock scaled up

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, scaling, wiremock, mockserver

Was looking for any common library in WireMock that would help when the mock server is scaled up. Currently I have a single server running on Ec2 that goes down during a deployment.

To have all my instances in sync with the stub mappings and journal request I was looking to persist them onto Dynamo DB.

1)For the Stub Mappings found MappingSource Class helpful to persist.But had a problem that it loads mappings only during application start up.

2)For Journal requests didn’t find any relevant class that would help me persist into any external database.

Have anyone else faced a similar problem when scaling up the Mockserver. Any insights to solve it.